# What is the name of this Vietnam War-related movie?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I am looking for a name of a movie that takes place in Vietnam or is related to Vietnam War (a movie describing someone's memories from the Vietnam War). I remember that the plot was focused on a man who fought in the War. He was desperate, saying he'll **"take a walk on train tracks", as a metaphor for commiting suicide**.

I remember the movie from my childhood and I'm looking for the title. I believe it might have been shot in the 80s or 90s (definitely no later than 1999).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Distant Thunder](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095036/) with John Lithgow. He watches a friend of his (and fellow Vietnam bush vet) commit suicide by "kissing a train."

Comment: This sounds right to me. Distant Thunder is from 1988 and in the film, Ralph Macchio's character says, "This is what they do. Kill their selves by walking into trains?"

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be the movie [Backfire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092609/). It's about a Vietnam vet who keeps having flashbacks that are pushing him towards suicide and his wife who is helping him along. I don't know specifically about the walk on the train tracks line.

Answer (score 2):

A movie very similar to the one just named (Backfire), has Don Johnson just before his *Miami Vice* days. I also don't remember the train track thing, and the suicide may not be his own, but that of his buddy. See if [Cease Fire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088892/combined) is the one you mean.
*Tim Murphy is a Vietnam Vet. When he loses his job he starts to relive all the pain and horror of his time in Vietnam. The stresses and strains nearly destroy his marriage and his family. Only after joining a veterans' therapy group does Tim find relief from his nightmares. With the support of his fellow vets and the love of his wife, Tim recovers.*

Answer (score 1):

It's not [Jacob's Ladder](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099871/), is it?

IMDb description:

> A traumatized Vietnam war veteran finds out that his post-war life
>   isn't what he believes it to be when he's attacked by horned creatures
>   in the subway and his dead son comes to visit him.

A user synopsis:

> New York postal worker Jacob Singer is trying to keep his frayed life
>   from unraveling. His days are increasingly being invaded by flashbacks
>   to his first marriage, his now-dead son, and his tour of duty in
>   Vietnam. Athough his new wife tries to help Jacob keep his grip on
>   sanity, the line between reality and delusion is steadily growing more
>   and more uncertain.

Comment: I've seen Jacob's Ladder recently, it's not it.